# Comparing two PDFs using Kullback-Leibler divergence

Tags: probability, distributions, python, kernel-smoothing, kullback-leibler

I am trying to compare two PDFs using Kullback-Leibler divergence but I am getting a value which means they are almost identical. Am I missing something?
Here is my code.

```
import numpy
import scipy.stats as ss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = numpy.random.rand(1000)
b = numpy.random.rand(650)
ag = ss.gaussian_kde(a)
bg = ss.gaussian_kde(b)
bk = numpy.linspace(numpy.min(b), numpy.max(b), 1000)
ak = numpy.linspace(numpy.min(a), numpy.max(a), 1000)
agv = ag(ak)
bgv = bg(bk)
e = ss.entropy(agv, bgv)
0.008704001913773865

plt.plot(ak,agv)
plt.show()
```

[image: a - PDF]

```
plt.plot(bk,bgv)
plt.show()
```

[image: b - PDF]

These two seems not equal. But why am I getting such a low entropy?

Comment: What does ss.entropy do? I'm not familiar with Python. In R I would integrate numerically density(a)*log(density(a)/density(b)), in 0,1.

Comment: @utobi https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html

Comment: Seems to do the right thing. However, although the KL value here may seem pretty small, it is not easy to say "how much small is small" ...

Comment: Is it too small? I mean both $a$ and $b$ are being sampled from uniform(0,1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the problem with divergences in general. As there isn't a scale for them it's not easy to say it's value is small.

**What I use to do is computing KL for two PDFs I know should be close. Results lower than this indicate the two PDFs are close. This can be understood as a "calibration" for the measure.**

Be aware that bigger the sample size, lower the divergence value. For instance, see how the color bar changes in the figures below (code based on yours: https://github.com/luizfrias/ica/blob/master/KL%20divergence%20test.ipynb)

[image]

[image]

Comment: In information theory, KL divergence does have a scale of bits.  So if a and b were two probability distributions of byte values, to convert from a to b you'd need additionally to use 0.0087 bits /byte of data.  And it is also bounded so that 0 < KL < 8 bits.